# Is August 15th a day of obligation for all Roman Catholics?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary

August 15th on which the assumption of St. Mary, mother of Jesus is commemorated by the  Catholic Church is a day of obligation for the Roman Catholics in India. I wish to know if the day is one of obligation for the universal Catholic Church, or is the practice restricted to India which commemorates its independence from British rule on the same day ?

Comment: Of the ten holy days of obligation mentioned in the Canon Law all but two have been suppressed by the Indian Bishops Conference, leaving only the Assumption and Christmas Day, both of which are public holidays, the Assumption being so only by coincidence with Independence Day, and Christmas in its own right. It is very likely that the Conference chose to retain the obligation on the Assumption, while relaxing it on other days, because  the public holiday makes it practical. Even some Catholic countries such as Brazil do not observe the Assumption as an obligation, but Catholics in the UK do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Assumption of the Blessed Virgin Mary is a holy day of obligation for the entire universal Church ([Code of Canon Law, 1246 §1](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P4N.HTM)).

At the same time it should be recalled that the conference of bishops can suppress or transfer some holy days of obligation with the permission of the Apostolic See ([Code of Canon Law, 1246 §2](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P4N.HTM)).

See also: [What are the Holy Days of Obligation? (Catholic Answers)](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/what-are-the-holy-days-of-obligation)

Comment: Is the Assumption the highest form of offering, I think it's a Solemnity not a Feast, that's why it's an obligation.

Comment: It is a Solemnity, which is the highest category, but not all solemnities are holy days of obligation.

Comment: Solemnity are only given to Jesus, but thru Dogmatic teaching it was extended to Mary that's what I've heard from our priest.So all solemnity are holy days of obligation.

Comment: [Here](https://relevantradio.com/2017/12/2018-holy-days-obligation-solemnities/) is a list of solemnities.  You will see that relatively few are holy days of obligation. Honestly the language is somewhat fluid.